# Is it correct to say "It was not happened"?

Tags: grammaticality, auxiliary-verbs

Is it correct to say "It was not happened"? I have heard people saying "It was not happening" or "It didn't happen" but "It was not happened" is new to me.

Answer (score 1):

The past progressive tense uses the past of *to be* with the present participle: "It was not happening". This tense is to say that something was - or in this case was not - happening continually over a period in the past.

The simple past is most often formed from the preterite form of the verb ("It happened"), but sometimes for emphasis, inversion of - as in this case - negation, it is formed with forms of *do*: "It didn't happen".

The form "It was not happened" doesn't match any construction for any tense, and is incorrect.

Comment: Downvoter care to comment?

Answer (score 1):

It is incorrect to say "It was not happened", because it is against the rules of tense - past tense, in this case.

It could be "It did not happen", in which case it will be [simple past](http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/simplepast.html).

"It was not happening" is [past continuous](http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/pastcontinuous.html) and differs in meaning from "It did not happen".

Hope the links will be of help to you.

Answer (score 0):

The verb “happen” can not take a direct object, and it therefore has no passive form, so there is no “is/was/be happened” tense. There are a number of English verbs like this: occur, arise, and exist are some others. Here’s [a link](http://www.monash.edu.au/lls/llonline/grammar/engineering/passive/3.xml) with a short discussion.

Comment: I think you're on the right path. But unfortunately your assumption that there cannot be a passive if the active version has no direct object is not true. That is, it is not a requirement that the active version have a direct object in order for a passive version to be possible. For example, *"These problems weren't faced up to by the committee"* and *"Not to go would be considered rude"*.